# How to get only operands with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to extract only operands viz. `+ - /` and `*` from my arithmetic expression.

E.g.: `A + B` should return me `+`

I tried using following few RegEx but I always get an array with 3 elements:

Expression #1:

`print_r (var_dump(preg_split ( "/([\w\s]*[^\-\+\/\*])/", "A+B" )), TRUE);`

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(0) ""
  [1] =>
  string(1) "+"
  [2] =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Expression #2:

```
print_r (var_dump(preg_split ( "/(?!\+|\-|\*|\/)[\w\s]+/", "A+B" )), TRUE);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(0) ""
  [1] =>
  string(1) "+"
  [2] =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I just want a `+` sign as output.

Any clue what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are your patterns so complex? What are the actual rules for extraction? If you just want to match a single operator in a string, use `preg_match('~[*/+-]~', $s, $matches)`. Use `preg_match_all` to get all occurrences.

Comment: Are you looking for a math parser in PHP? Try https://github.com/chriskonnertz/string-calc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wiktor said you'd better use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), but if you really want to use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) use the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` and simplify your regex:

```
print_r (var_dump(preg_split ( "/[\w\s]/", "A+B", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY )), TRUE);
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "+"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *preg_match_all* :

```
preg_match_all ( "/([\^\-\+\/\*])/", "A+B", $result );
$result = $result[0];
print_r($result);
```

The result is :

```
Array ( [0] => + )
```

Comment: Please, don't give an answer directly taken from comments.